# Do I have to save the session when the user is logged?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm starting developing a Facebook app with PHP SDK, I have a two doubs regarding the auth/login process.

I have this code:

```
  require_once("facebook.php");

  $config = array();
  $config[‘appId’] = 'xxxxxx';
  $config[‘secret’] = 'xxxxxx';
  $config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);

  $user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Now I have the first doubt, doing something like:

```
if ($user === 0) { .... }
```

Question:
- does it check if the user is LOGGED or whether the user has authorized the app ? (obviously when `$user != 0` )

then, I show the auth dialog to let user choose if authorize or not my application, in this manner:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array{
     'scope' => 'read_stream',
     'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/login.php'
});
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
```

Question:
Do I have to use this code if $user returns 0 ? I mean, what is the scope of this code? Login on Facebook or the app Authorization ?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have typographic quotes in your code? did you write the question in MS Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it check if the user is LOGGED or whether the user has authorized the app ?

It checks if the user is logged into facebook and authorized the app (with a valid token).

> Do I have to use this code if $user returns 0 ? I mean, what is the scope of this code? Login on Facebook or the app Authorization ?

The scope of this code is app authorization.

If `$user` is 0 use that piece of code to redirect to Facebook's authorization/login page (if the user hasn't authorized the app or if he did but the token is not valid) after that it will be redirected to `https://www.myapp.com/login.php?state=$s&code=$NEW_TOKEN`
And the facebook php library will handle `$_REQUEST['code']` so that $user will return the user's facebook ID.

Comment: thank you for the reply, Ok, I have understand...only one thing.. What do I have to do with TOKEN? Do I have to manage it mysql OR php sdk will do it automatically ?

Comment: No, the php-sdk does it automatically for you, after the user is redirected from `$loginUrl`

EDIT:
If i may suggest you should create test users (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ then choose the app and go to roles) to try different scenarios.

And here is a pseudo-code for logging in and getting the info http://pastebin.com/GjvRqxCy <- Not this is pseudo-code not supposed to be perfect, use it for testing/learning.